# Javascript window

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have been trying to fix this for quite some time now: I can't access the url of the window because it's on another domain.. Some solutions?

```
function login() {
        var cb = window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600'); 

        var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(function() { 
            if (cb.document.url.indexOf(REDIRECT) >= 0) {
                window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                var url =   cb.document.url;
                acToken =   gup(url, 'access_token');
                tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
                expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');
                cb.close();

                validateToken(acToken);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
```

Comment: Didn't try, but can Request.UrlReferrer be helpfull somehow?

Comment: If not under the same domain forget about it, as it falls under the SOP.

Comment: but what if the url (domain) of the window is a callback to my own domain where i have access? (im working with oauth2 for google client side)

Comment: doesnt change anything. You cant do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with IE9 and I found the solution : add try{} catch{} and increase the time of the pollTimer 
giving :

```
    function login() {
    var cb = window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600'); 

    var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(function() { 
        try {
            if (cb.document.url.indexOf(REDIRECT) >= 0) {
                window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                var url =   cb.document.url;
                acToken =   gup(url, 'access_token');
                tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
                expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');
                cb.close();

                validateToken(acToken);
            }
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, no solution for crossdomain policy hijacking. [Here some quick overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) from mozilla developer.

If you explain what exactly you have to do with the `document.url` property from the other domain maybe someone founds a workaround.

Comment: It's possible to access HTTP based google API's, but not for general crossdomain access.

Comment: i'm trying an app in Phonegap to authenticate with google oauth2.. it is possible with facebook & twitter.. why not with Google ?

Comment: I meaned it's possible to access HTTP based Google API's using Google's OAuth2 library. Please see @GGG's comment on your post for circumstances to  the SOP.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the content of _url?

In that case you can let it return it's content via javascript with `document.write` and then include it on your current page by referencing it via `<script type="text/javascript" src="_url" />`

After this, you can access the content of _url through the DOM as you like.